# Select Build Variant menu item greyed out

Tags: android, android-studio

In Android Studio 3.0.1 I tried to go to Build > Select Build Variant but the option "Select Build Variant" was greyed out.  How do I access this menu option?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

I found that the "Select Build Variant" menu item became available as long as I wasn't viewing the project-level build.gradle file.  While editing the project-level build.gradle file, the menu option was grayed out.  But if I opened a different file, for example a module-level build.gradle file, the "Select Build Variant" menu item became available.

Comment: Hmm... I'm running Android Studio 3.4.1, and find that Select Build Variant is greyed out even when not editing anything. ... oh I guess I need to also select the Project in order to have it appear.

Comment: I did **build**, then clicked the link to **analyze**, and wound up looking at **app-debug.apk** and couldn't **Select Build Variant...** until I closed the **app-debug.apk** window.

Answer (score 2):

Had the same problem. Switched to Android Level Level View and the menu wasn't greyed out any more